# How to sort an array in assembler?

Tags: x86, nasm

The question for me is: to rearrange all the individual numbers in the number in order to get the largest number. I'm using the SASM compiler, so the text may be different from most people's.
I can give an example:
input: 1229
output: 9221
It's not just the reverse, but the four numbers 1, 2, 2, and 9 are used to recombine the largest number. I have some ideas myself, which is to disassemble the numbers and put them in an array, and then find the maximum value first, and then find the second maximum value. . . . Finally find the minimum. It is equivalent to sorting the array in descending order. But I can't realize it, because the teacher does not allow me to use functions to achieve it.

```
%include"io.inc"
section .bss
N equ 10
a resd N
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    ;Divide by 10, put the resulting number into a[i]
    GET_DEC 4, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ecx, 10
cycle:  
    cmp eax, 0
    je exit
    xor edx, edx
    cdq
    idiv ecx
    mov [a+4*ebx], edx;put remainder into array
    inc ebx
    jmp cycle
exit:
    
    
    
    mov ecx, 10
    dec ecx
L:  
    push ecx;stack, retaining the value of ecx
    mov ebx, 0
L1:
    mov eax, [a+4*ebx]
    inc ebx
    mov edx, [a+4*ebx]
    ;Comparison of size
    cmp ebx, edx
    jle next
    ;swap array memory
    xchg eax, [a+4*ebx]
    dec ebx
    mov [a+4*ebx], eax
 
next:
    inc ebx
    loop L1
    pop ecx;
    loop L
    
    ;Print
    xor ebx, ebx
print:
    cmp ebx, 10;After printing 10 times, stop on the 11th
    je noplay
    mov eax, [a+4*ebx]
    cmp eax, 0;Do not print 0
    je toout
    PRINT_DEC 4, [a+4*ebx]
    inc ebx
    jmp print
toout:
    inc ebx
    jmp print
noplay:
    NEWLINE
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem, it would be more perfect if not using the stack, because we just learned the stack, many times I can't understand what the program is doing.

Comment: If you read input as a string, it already is an array of decimal digits.  (As 1-byte ASCII characters which you can sort.  Or if you just need the max, loop over once.)  The `GET_DEC` function will have already converted a digit-string to a binary integer for you, so dividing by 10 repeatedly to extract the decimal digits is just undoing that process.